# How do I listen for a keyboard combination globally?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

How would I have my C# program listen for a specific keyboard combination (say, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) globally. Even if my application is minimized I would want it to intercept this and do something.

Comment: You can also take a look at [http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207) which is written in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the Windows API to set a system hook into the keyboard.  Here is a pretty good article on how to do such a thing:

http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/keyboard/article.php/c4829/